# HTML/Angular create scrollable <select> dropdown?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Hello I have been trying to create a dropdown list with  and  while avoiding libraries like Angular material. [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf6H7.png)

What I am aiming for is to show a limited amount of options and make the rest viewable by adding a scrollbar to the dropdown menu. I have been trying different approaches but couldn't find one that suits my specific requirement.

```css
.field{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 12px;

    position: static;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    left: calc(50% - 449px/2);
    top: 32px;

    /* UI/White */

    background: #FFFFFF;
    /* UI/Grey/stroke */

    border: 1px solid #BBC0C9;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* shadow-focus */

    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 2px #FED79A;
    border-radius: 4px;

    /* Inside auto layout */

    flex: none;
    order: 1;
    align-self: stretch;
    flex-grow: 0;
    margin: 8px 0px;

    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<select  class="field">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>- select item -</option>
    <option> test1 </option>
    <option> test2 </option>
    <option> test3 </option>
    <option> test4 </option>
    <option> test5 </option>
    <option> test6 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Uhm, forget all that CSS stuff - and simply set the `size` attribute? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-size (Needs `multiple` as well.)

Comment: @CBroe Size turned the drop down into a list box.  I'm curious as to why the OP wants to create his own.

Comment: @CBroe I'm sorry I don't seem to quite understand if I add size and multiple attributes it converts my dropdown into a scrollable list which I don't want since I need the list to drop down on click.

Comment: Well then you will have to build your own component out of HTML & CSS (and maybe additional JS) - you can not get this with a `select` element. (The browser _might_ over a scrollbar for the opened `select` field, if there are more options than can fit the screen, but you have no control over it.)